# Python request post method failing with attribute error

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to post json data to API POST call but getting attribute error. Can someone help me to figure out the issue with below code please.

The payload_json data shown below is being pulled from snowflake database using object_construct function to populate data in key:value pairs. And the result set will be returned in tuple. I have used below conversion to convert from tuple to list and that produces single quotes around each item it seems. Not sure if this is causing the issue. It would be great if anyone suggest to overcome this issue.

I wanted to post the data from DB as JSON.

```
cursor.execute(payload_sql)
payload_json = cursor.fetchall()
payload_json = list(sum(payload_json, ()))
```

Sample output would be like below for payload_json variable

```
payload_json = ['{"key1": "abc","key2":"123"}','{"key1":"def","key2":"456"}']

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-api-key': 'api_key'}
postdata = {"is_ingestion_finished": "true", "job_id": "", "chunk_number": 1, "payload": 
payload_json}

result = requests.post('api_url', data=postdata, headers=headers, verify=False )
print(result.content)
```

Error returned when making the POST call.

```
{"errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'get'", "errorType": "AttributeError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"data_storage_engine/app.py\", line 10, in handler\n    response = run(event)\n", "  File \"/function/data_storage_engine/clean_data.py\", line 40, in run\n    data_rows = body.get('payload')\n"]}
```

However this works fine when making POST request via CURL

```
curl -L api_url -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -H 'x-api-key: api_key'  -d '{"is_ingestion_finished": true, "job_id": "", "chunk_number": 1, "payload": [{"key1": "abc","key2":"123"},{"key1":"def","key2":"456"}]}'
```

Comment: What version of python and python-requests are you using? for me your code works fine. From the looks of the error message, it seems that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @0xInfection using following version "Python 3.6.2" and "requests 2.18.4"

Comment: ok @0xInfection.. Seems like the payload_json is coming as list with single quotes. Is that something causing issue?
`payload_json = ['{"key1": "abc","key2":"123"}','{"key1":"def","key2":"456"}']`

Note the payload_json is being pulled from DB table using snowflake object_construct function to populate as key:value pairs and the result set is stored as tuple. I have used following conversion to make tuple into list and that produces single quote `payload_json = cursor.fetchall()`
`payload_json = list(sum(payload_json, ()))`